# Size parameter and how it ties with Scan and Scroll to fetch all results?

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, scroll, lucene

I want to be able to fetch all results of my query using the scan and scroll API.

As per ES documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-scrolling.html) , the size parameter sets how many hits per shard should be fetched.

Is it that each batch of results with corresponding scroll ID for the next batch, represent the number of hits (<=size) from each shard?

Does that imply that scan and scroll ignores the rest of the results in a shard if size< sizeOfResultsInShard, and moves over to the next shard? Or does that imply that it will still scroll through the next batch of results from the same shard instead of moving over to another shard?

If we only fetch 'size' number of results per shard, then is the only way for me to fetch all results from each shard that I set a BIG NUMBER as the size parameter? Not sure how big the big number should be! Wish there were a simpler way to fetch all the results instead of making random guesses at a size value greater than the number of results possible per shard.

Answer (score 0):

scroll : allows us to keep pulling batches of results from Elasticsearch until there are no more results left. It’s a bit like a cursor in a traditional database.

size : the size parameter sets how many hits per shard should be fetched.

In short, Scroll search is used to fetch all the documents matching the query. Size specifies how many hits per shard should be fetched but the total records fetched by a single scroll could be much more than size if multiple shards are involved.

> Is it that each batch of results with corresponding scroll ID for the
>   next batch, represent the number of hits (<=size) from each shard?

Yes. These represent the next batch of hits from each shard.

> Does that imply that scan and scroll ignores the rest of the results
>   in a shard if size< sizeOfResultsInShard, and moves over to the next
>   shard?

No, it does not. In the next scroll it fetches the next `size` number of records. If size >remainingResults, only remainingResults will be fetched from this shard.

> Or does that imply that it will still scroll through the next batch of
>   results from the same shard instead of moving over to another shard?

Yes, it will until the results are exhausted.

Comment: I find a discrepancy in saying that 'size' number of results are fetched from each shard v/s saying that if the no. of results in 1 shard are more than the size, then the next batch of results would also include results from the same shard as before until all results are returned. So, would it be right to say that we don't actually get size number of results per shard BUT get size number of results in each batch? Eg. 2 shards with 100 docs each matching query. Size = 10. Would I get 10 results each from shard 1 and shard 2? Or would I get 10 batches of 10 results from shard 1 and shard2 each?

Comment: that depends on the number of indexes in the query.. if there are multiple indexes then the results would be fetched from multiple shards